# Find out time between two records

Tags: mysql

So here is the scenario i have a table which logs gps data from the device along with the engine status(on or off). I need to find out how much time the engine status was on and off.

```
vehicle_id | engine_status | time_stamp
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 07:30:02
 2         |    off        |2014-05-21 07:40:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 07:50:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 08:00:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 08:10:02
 2         |    on         |2014-05-21 08:20:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 08:30:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 08:40:02
 2         |    on         |2014-05-21 08:50:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:00:02
 2         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:10:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:10:06
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:30:02
 2         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:30:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:35:02
 2         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:39:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:40:02
 1         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:45:02
 2         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:50:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:55:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:56:02
 2         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:58:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:59:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 09:59:02
 1         |    on         |2014-05-21 10:10:02
 2         |    off        |2014-05-21 09:30:02
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (vehicle_id INT NOT NULL
 ,engine_status VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,time_stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 07:30:02'),
 (2,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 07:40:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 07:50:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 08:00:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 08:10:02'),
 (2,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 08:20:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 08:30:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 08:40:02'),
 (2,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 08:50:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:00:02'),
 (2,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:10:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:10:06'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:30:02'),
 (2,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:30:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:35:02'),
 (2,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:39:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:40:02'),
 (1,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:45:02'),
 (2,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:50:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:55:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:56:02'),
 (2,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:58:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:59:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 09:59:02'),
 (1,'on'         ,'2014-05-21 10:10:02'),
 (2,'off'        ,'2014-05-21 09:30:02');

 SELECT vehicle_id
      , engine_status
      , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end,start)))) total
   FROM
      (
 SELECT a.vehicle_id
      , a.engine_status
      , a.time_stamp start
      , MIN(c.time_stamp) end 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN @prev= vehicle_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
             , @prev:=vehicle_id 
          FROM my_table
             , ( SELECT @i:=1,@prev:='')x 
         ORDER 
            BY vehicle_id
             , time_stamp
      ) a
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN @prev= vehicle_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
             , @prev:=vehicle_id 
          FROM my_table
             , ( SELECT @i:=1,@prev:='')x 
         ORDER 
            BY vehicle_id
             , time_stamp
      ) b  
     ON b.vehicle_id = a.vehicle_id 
    AND b.engine_status = a.engine_status
    AND b.rank = a.rank - 1  
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN @prev= vehicle_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
             , @prev:=vehicle_id 
          FROM my_table
             , ( SELECT @i:=1,@prev:='')x 
         ORDER 
            BY vehicle_id
             , time_stamp
      ) c 
     ON c.vehicle_id = a.vehicle_id
    AND c.engine_status = a.engine_status
    AND c.rank >= a.rank 
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT *
             , CASE WHEN @prev= vehicle_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
             , @prev:=vehicle_id 
          FROM my_table
             , ( SELECT @i:=1,@prev:='')x 
         ORDER 
            BY vehicle_id
             , time_stamp
      ) d 
     ON d.vehicle_id = c.vehicle_id  
    AND d.engine_status = c.engine_status
    AND d.rank = c.rank + 1 
  WHERE b.rank IS NULL 
    AND c.rank IS NOT NULL
    AND d.rank IS NULL
  GROUP 
     BY a.vehicle_id
      , a.engine_status
      , a.rank
      ) x
   GROUP BY vehicle_id, engine_status;
+------------+---------------+----------+
| vehicle_id | engine_status | total    |
+------------+---------------+----------+
|          1 | off           | 01:15:00 |
|          1 | on            | 00:55:00 |
|          2 | off           | 00:08:00 |
|          2 | on            | 01:10:00 |
+------------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: I like it.. +1. Looking at your query I lake my words back that it is not possible using query. But I still think SP might be a better way of doing it. But anyways.. cheers

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the help. I c that vehicle 2 on time is 70 minutes. But if u look at the data, vehcle 2 on happend at 8:20 and off @ 9:50 . so  the on time should be 90 minutes right?

Comment: It was on from 8.20 to 9.30 (70 mins). However, it was on again from 9.39 to (presumably) 9.50 11 mins). Perhaps this query needs a slight tweak to reflect that.

Comment: This is why I STRESS the importance of providing the DESIRED RESULT SET. (We might have to JOIN this query to itself [yuk])

Answer (score 3):

***Query updated***

I juste finished another query, with better perfs :

```
SELECT
    vehicle_id,
    engine_status,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end, start)))) time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        vehicle_id, 
        engine_status,
        time_stamp AS start,
        (
            SELECT MIN(time_stamp)
            FROM engine_statuses ends
            WHERE ends.time_stamp > starts.time_stamp
            AND ends.vehicle_id = starts.vehicle_id
            AND ends.engine_status <> starts.engine_status
        ) AS end        
    FROM engine_statuses starts
    GROUP BY vehicle_id, end
    HAVING end IS NOT NULL
) t
GROUP BY vehicle_id, engine_status
```

**Results**

```
+------------+---------------+----------+
| vehicle_id | engine_status | time     |
+------------+---------------+----------+
| 1          | on            | 01:00:00 |
| 1          | off           | 01:25:00 |
| 2          | on            | 01:30:00 |
| 2          | off           | 00:49:00 |
+------------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: Your query is giving the desired op.. how do i calculate the offtime??[link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca781/7

Comment: Simply reverse the query. I edited my answer to give you the full query.

Comment: query is taking too much time to execute. around  10 mins for 2 days of data.. :(

Comment: @user3659794 I just found a better way to combine both queries. This will **only** work with `on/off` status.

Answer (score 1):

If the vehicle_id is an aggregation level and the status is mantained till the next record for the same vehicle_id

```
SELECT vehicle_id, Last_Status AS engine_status
     , SUM(Dur) / 60 AS 'total(Minutes)'
FROM   (SELECT a.vehicle_id
             , a.engine_status
             , a.time_stamp
             , @last_status := @status AS Last_Status
             , @status := a.engine_status
             , @last_time := @time
             , @time := a.time_stamp
             , TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.time_stamp, @last_time)) AS Dur
        FROM   my_table a
        WHERE  vehicle_id = 1
        ORDER BY time_stamp) AS D
WHERE Dur >= 0
GROUP BY vehicle_id, Last_Status
UNION ALL
SELECT vehicle_id, Last_Status AS engine_status
     , SUM(Dur) / 60 AS 'total(Minutes)'
FROM   (SELECT a.vehicle_id
             , a.engine_status
             , a.time_stamp
             , @last_status := @status AS Last_Status
             , @status := a.engine_status
             , @last_time := @time
             , @time := a.time_stamp
             , TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.time_stamp, @last_time)) AS Dur
        FROM   my_table a
        WHERE  vehicle_id = 2
        ORDER BY time_stamp) AS D
WHERE Dur >= 0
GROUP BY vehicle_id, Last_Status
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d8428/14) it gives values different from the one from Strawberry, but without any words from the OP probably caused by different assumptions

If only the engine_status is the aggregator

```
SELECT Last_Status AS engine_status
     , SUM(Dur) / 60 AS 'total(Minutes)'
FROM   (SELECT a.vehicle_id
             , a.engine_status
             , a.time_stamp
             , @last_status := @status AS Last_Status
             , @status := a.engine_status
             , @last_time := @time
             , @time := a.time_stamp
             , TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.time_stamp, @last_time)) AS Dur
        FROM   my_table a
        ORDER BY time_stamp) AS D
WHERE Dur >= 0
GROUP BY Last_Status
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d8428/16)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood is properly, I think you can not do it using a single query. You need a stored procedure. here are the steps which should work

1. Create a Stored Proc
2. Select and loop on the data of the table
3. Find out the changing status and the times. Lets say the current row in off status, find out the most near on status and find the difference in time using HOUR(TIMEDIFF(date1, date2)) (IN MYSQL)  . So now you have th time difference between the status change
4. use a temp table to calculate your time

I am not very sure if this is what you want .. Try wring it in a stored proc.. I think it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree.

Comment: I also think this is doable in single query

Comment: can you provide a sample query to start with?

Comment: @user3659794 I just built a query to do it. See my answer.

Comment: I suspect it comes down to a choice between performance vs. scalability. If you know that there will only be two states (on and off) then it's possible that @zessx's solution (untested) will perform better. If there's potential for more states (or if my query happens to be faster) then it's a 'no brainer'.

Answer (score 0):

Following query counts the time between a record with engine_status='on' and its previous record. All these intervals are summed per vehicle_id (tested on DB2).The time between a 'on' record followed by and 'off' record is not counted.

```
select vehicle_id, sum(tt1.time_stamp - coalesce((select max(time_stamp)
                               from timetable tt2 
                              where tt1.vehicle_id = tt2.vehicle_id 
                                and tt2.time_stamp < tt1.time_stamp
                             ),
                            time_stamp))
from timetable tt1
where engine_status = 'on'
group by vehicle_id
```